# How to add (or create) a String Collection Editor control in my Windows Form in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.7.2

I develop a Windows Forms application with C#. Inside the application I have a Form and, inside this form, I want to create something like a table / list-of-strings, to be able to give user the functionality to enter or delete it's strings.

The functionality I want to achieve is like the String Collection Editor you can find in a the ComboBox control, when you go in Properties -> Items -> [(Collection) ...]:

[image]

Does this control already exists in the Toolbox of Visual Studio? I cannot find something similar.

If not, how can I create it?

(Also, as an extension of the functionality of it, I want furthermore to add a "delete" button in each string entry, to be able the user to delete entries of the table. How can I also achieve this as a next step?)

I am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 - v15.9.14 and my application targets the .Net Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: Consider a [`DataGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview).

Comment: The ComboBox items editor in the form designer is a simple multi-line TextBox control.

Comment: Well, that's the standard editor used with a string collection (a string array). You just need a Property declared as `public string[] MyStringArrayProperty { get; set; }`. Or specify this editor type for your (compatible) collection.

Comment: Are you going to show the editor at run-time or at design-time? What's the class type? (control? component? a plain class?) What's the property type? (`string[]`, `List<string>`, ...)

Answer (score 1):

A simple and straightforward way is to create a DataGridView without row&column header and border to hold the string.

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn tc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
tc.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(tc);

// Hide row&column header
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
// Hide border
dataGridView1.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.None;
```

The test result,

[image]